# NFC service dead - attempting to recover

Tags: android, nfc

I have an application which reads & writes the data into the NFC tag(Type 2).
Some times while reading the tag i am getting the below error in LogCat.

```
03-13 12:26:12.946: E/NFC(18889): NFC service dead - attempting to recover
03-13 12:26:12.946: E/NFC(18889): android.os.DeadObjectException
03-13 12:26:12.946: E/NFC(18889):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
03-13 12:26:12.946: E/NFC(18889):   at android.nfc.INfcAdapter$Stub$Proxy.setForegroundDispatch(INfcAdapter.java:350)
03-13 12:26:12.946: E/NFC(18889):   at android.nfc.NfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatchInternal(NfcAdapter.java:1062)
03-13 12:26:12.946: E/NFC(18889):   at android.nfc.NfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(NfcAdapter.java:1050)
```

Does any have any idea why is this happening. Is there any way to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be a problem of the available power in your Android device: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432796/android-nfc-issue-with-apdu-commands

Answer (score 2):

I have come across the same issue and was able to resolve.
This happens when you try to invoke NFC beam, when Activity is **not in Resumed State**.

NFCBeamShareData checks if the current activity is in resume state. If the current activity is not in resume state, it will return null object and causes **NullPointerException** or **DeadObjectException**.